# How to convert Android spannable to markdown syntex

Tags: android, markdown, editor, android-spannable

I'm working on a custom Android editor that is actually based on Android Spannable rendering and later converts the Spannable to Markdown syntax for other clients.

it supports

- BOLD
- ITALIC
- STRIKETHROUGH
- BULLETED LIST
- ORDERED LIST

To achieve markdown to Spanaalbe conversion, I'm using the [Markwon](https://github.com/noties/Markwon) library and it's working well.

Rendering via Spannable is achievable but the final custom conversion from Spannable to Markdown syntax, it's looking very complex and needed to handle a lot of edge cases.

1. Do we have any existing solution that converts Spannable to Markdown syntax?
2. If No, then what's the best way to achieve it?

Comment: Requests for libraries are off topic here.